# How can you split string in C++ and store them in variables?

Tags: c++, string, split, strtok

For example, the string is: `namespace:name` but I want to get only namespace, how can I do that?
I tried this but I don't know how to output only the `namespace`

```
char id[] = "namespace:name";
char* token = strtok(id, ":");
while (token != NULL)
{
  printf("%s\n", token);
  token = strtok(NULL, ":");
}
```

Comment: You can't figure out how to only output the first token ?

Comment: A quick thing to notice is the tag info for [tag:strtok], in particular the mention that it is a C function. Since you want C++, you should start by using [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of C-style strings.

Comment: Or are you more interested in finding out how to change `while (token != NULL)` to `if (token != NULL)`?

Comment: I just want to output the namespace somehow, like for example, in Java we can just do `String[] id = identifier.split(":");` and then store them in variable like `String idName = id[1];` (Btw, identifier is supposed to be `namespace:name`). I want to do the same thing but in C++